# file exist in php download

Tags: php, download

I'm download file but i want. IF file exist from drive C i can download, 
ELSE IF file exist automatic can donwload file from drive D . Else "File Not Found" 
i'm confused :(

This is my quoute script

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$query  = "SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id = '$id'";
$jl  = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($jl);

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$data['name']);

header("Content-length: ".$data['size']);

header("Content-type: ".$data['type']);

$filename = $data['name'];

if (file_exists($filename)) {
$fp  = fopen("d:/result/".$data['name'], 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize('d:/result/'.$data['name']));
fclose($fp);
} 

else if (file_exists($filename))   {
$fp  = fopen("c:/result/".$data['name'], 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize('c:/result/'.$data['name']));
fclose($fp);
}

else  {
echo "File Not Found";
}

// show file download 
echo $content;

exit;
```

Comment: you use pure (and BTW un-filtered (NEVER trust user input!!!)) filename for BOTH file_exists() calls .. but then try to open something where that name is only part of the path .. this code is totally confused, no wonder you are.

Comment: This code use for backup file, i'm already copy some my file from C to D so i want this case fix :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify the list of paths in an array.

```
$paths ['c:/result/', 'd:/result/];
```

then you loop through these paths:

```
foreach($paths as $path){
    if(file_exists($path.$data['name'])){
        print file_get_contents($path.$data['name']);
    }
}
```

Full solution for you:

```
//prevent sql injection
$data  = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id = '".intval($_GET['id'])."'"));
//now you can add as much paths as you like
$paths = [
    'd:/result/',
    'c:/result/'
];

foreach ($paths as $path) {
    if (file_exists($path . $data['name'])) {
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $data['name']."; ".
               "Content-length: " . $data['size']."; ".
               "Content-type: " . $data['type']);

        print file_get_contents($path . $data['name']);
        exit;
    }
}

echo "File not found";
exit;
```

Comment: Thank's Lauri Orgla, It's Work ^_^

Comment: The pleasure is all mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is backwards. You've output your `content` headers already, so if the file doesn't exist, your user will be downloading a file whose contents are "File Not Found". That'd just confuse them when they double-click on their pdf/word/whatever file and get a "file is corrupted" error.

Your code should be more like:

```
$c_source = 'C:/...';
$d_source = 'D:/...';

if (is_readable($c_source)) {
    header(...);   // <--do this only if you found a file
    readfile($c_source);
} else if (is_readable($d_source)) {
    header(...); // do this only if you found a file
    readfile($d_source);
} else {
    die("File not found");
}
```